# More general way of generating PyODBC queries as a dict?

Tags: python, database, dictionary, pyodbc

Here are my averagely general class methods for creating a dictionary from the result of database queries:

```
def make_schema_dict(self):
    schema = [i[2] for i in self.cursor.tables()
              if i[2].startswith('tbl_') or i[2].startswith('vw_')]

    self.schema = {table: {'scheme': [row.column_name for row
                                      in self.cursor.columns(table)]}
                   for table in schema}

def last_table_query_as_dict(self, table):
    return {'data': [{col: row.__getattribute__(col) for col in self.schema[table]['scheme']
                      if col != 'RowNum'} for row in self.cursor.fetchall()]}
```

Unfortunately as you can see, there are many complications.

For example, when multiple tables are queried; some hackish lambdas are required to generate the resulting dictionary.

Can you think of some more general methods?

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to use [row.cursor_description](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Rows#cursor_description) to make this a lot simpler.  This should get you a list of dictionaries for the results:

```
    [{c[0]: v for (c, v) in zip(row.cursor_description, row)} for row in self.cursor.fetchall()]
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like a great solution. Voted up.

Answer (score 2):

A neat solution can be found in this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/pyodbc/BVIZBYGXNsk

The root of the idea being, subclass Connection to use a custom Cursor class, have the Cursor class automatically construct dicts for you. I'd call this a fancy pythonic solution. You could also just have an additional function fetchonedict() and extend the Cursor class rather than override so you could retain default behavior.

```
class ConnectionWrapper(object): 
    def __init__(self, cnxn): 
        self.cnxn = cnxn 

    def __getattr__(self, attr): 
        return getattr(self.cnxn, attr) 

    def cursor(self): 
        return CursorWrapper(self.cnxn.cursor()) 

class CursorWrapper(object): 
    def __init__(self, cursor): 
        self.cursor = cursor 

    def __getattr__(self, attr): 
        return getattr(self.cursor, attr) 

    def fetchone(self): 
        row = self.cursor.fetchone() 
        if not row: 
            return None 
        return dict((t[0], value) for t, value in zip (self.cursor.description, row))
```

Additionally, while not for PyODBC, check out this stackoverflow answer for links to DictCursor classes for MySQL and OurSQL if you need some inspiration for design.

Comment: Thanks for this; will test it a little later. I'm guessing getting it to work with `fetchmany` and `fetchall` would be trivial. Voting this up.